# How to highlight active (variable) link in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I know how to 'highlight' an active link in React.js, I do it like this:

```
<Link
  className={splitted[1] === 'Details'
    ? "bg-red-800 rounded-full hover:text-white"
    : "hover:bg-blue-800 rounded-full hover:text-white"
  }
  key={'xxx'}
  to={`/Details/${id}`}
>
  This is my link            
</Link>
```

(ok, maybe a bit overkill, but it works)

But I have problems doing the same with a bunch of links that are rendered via a mapping. I try to do the same but it doesn't work at all. What is wrong in the code below?

```
const renderedLinks = links.map((link) => {
  return (
    <Link
      className={splitted[1] === `${link.path}`
        ? "bg-red-800 rounded-full hover:text-white"
        : "hover:bg-blue-800 rounded-full hover:text-white"
      }
      key={link.label}
      to={link.path}
    >
      {link.label}
    </Link>
  )
});
```

So, how do I get the variable `link.path` into this?

Links are generated by this:

```js
const links = [
  { label: 'Details', path: '/Details' },
  ...
]
```

And `splitted` is is the first path of the `pathname` obtained by `useLocation`.

I am using `react-router-dom@6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the `Link` component it would be better to use the [`NavLink`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link) component as it has logic baked-in to handle matching an active link to the current URL path. Use the `className` callback to access the `isActive` prop and conditionally apply the appropriate CSS classes.

Example:

```
<Link
  key={'xxx'}
  to={`/Details/${id}`}
  className={({ isActive }) => 
    [
      "rounded-full hover:text-white",
      isActive ? "bg-red-800" : "hover:bg-blue-800"
    ].join(" ")
  }
>
  This is my link            
</Link>
```

```
const renderedLinks = links.map((link) => (
  <Link
    key={link.path}
    to={link.path}
    className={({ isActive }) => 
      [
        "rounded-full hover:text-white",
        isActive ? "bg-red-800" : "hover:bg-blue-800"
      ].join(" ")
    }
  >
    {link.label}            
  </Link>
));
```

If you render links to both parent and child/descendent paths, i.e. `"/details"` and `"/details/specificDetails"` then you can also specify the `end` prop on the `NavLink` so the active link is matched by the end of the path.

> If the `end` prop is used, it will ensure this component isn't matched
> as "active" when its descendant paths are matched. For example, to
> render a link that is only active at the website root and not any
> other URLs, you can use:
>
> ```
> <NavLink to="/" end>
>   Home
> </NavLink>
> ```

Applied to your code:

```
const renderedLinks = links.map((link) => (
  <Link
    key={link.path}
    to={link.path}
    className={({ isActive }) => 
      [
        "rounded-full hover:text-white",
        isActive ? "bg-red-800" : "hover:bg-blue-800"
      ].join(" ")
    }
    end // <--
  >
    {link.label}            
  </Link>
));
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I was mixing a combination of link and navlink. Thanks a lot!